# Which is faster, client side or server side dom appending?

Tags: c#, javascript, ajax, asp.net-mvc-3

In an asp.net mvc3 view, I have a `$.get()` ajax call to a controller action which returns 80 lines of html code. Is it faster (from the `.get` call to finished rendering) to do the dom element creation on server side then just pass in one huge element to be appended to the DOM, or is it faster to just pass in a lot of raw data to the client side and then do all the DOM creation and appending there?

The html returned (or generated) creates a dashboard with about 5 layers of nested divs, some spans, text, etc.

Comment: @ta.speot.is - Server is of average speed, nothing fancy. Client is whoever browses in.

Comment: Typically appending large blocks of HTML is faster than the building up the DOM because of the way browsers handle it behind the scenes.  Though, I unfortunately cannot cite that.  (Meaning I'm basically speculating :p)

Comment: Seems to just make sense to distribute as much of the computing as possible. If you have 1000 different clients connecting, would you rather have one machine do that part of the work, or 1000 machines?

Comment: @cliffsofinsanity - depends on if those 1000 machines are pedal bikes or jet engines. In other words, the server handles string creation rather quickly whereas at times client side can struggle with DOM element creation.

Comment: @TravisJ: Are we talking about 10000 elements or more like hundreds? Even if the former, I'd still do it on the client, and just do some asynchronous processing of the data so that the user experience doesn't suffer.

Comment: Recently big sites like Twitter and Google plus have adopted for client side templating vs server side templating. This offloads some of the server work and rely on the browser to generate the HTML (or fragment/elements) and insert it into the DOM. Depending on your target audience and product this can be good or bad. I think this question should be reworded or closed as, in it's current context, it cannot be answered (we are not on your server and we do not know your client minimum requirements).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you do your own benchmarks because this depends on a lot of factors, like your audience device (computer/mobile), internet speeds, data plan etc. Know your target audience first and do what's better.

Returning formatted HTML is heavy on the traffic, but allows you to append it directly to the DOM. This is fine for people on a laptop/desktop who have broadband.

Returning raw data is faster but will make you create the DOM on the spot. However, this is usually ideal on high powered machines or mobile devices who have contracts whose payments are based on the amount of data transferred.

Comment: Will do. I am always curious about standardized methods, but so often it seems I just get to do it myself :) Works out for me, I enjoy rolling my own.

Comment: @TravisJ: by the way, for client side DOM manipulation, it could be useful to learn some JavaScript templating with [EJS](http://embeddedjs.com/getting_started.html) or any similar JavaScript templating libraries.

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - I use the razor engine to produce javascript from c# if it needs to have anything too complex. Otherwise, using strings as html is pretty bad practice in my opinion. I try to stick to creating actual elements. `var el = document.createElement("div")` and then working with those. `var sp = document.createElement("span")`, `el.appendChild(sp)` type of stuff. It allows a more dynamic environment to be setup where variables are easily inserted.

Comment: @TravisJ: did you scroll down the linked page at all?! Did you look at the examples of EJS? Its purpose (similar to other templating libraries) is to PREVENT concatenating HTML strings, because it's a really bad and ugly practice... I agree, HTML string concatenation has to be avoided. You should look at the examples of these templating libraries. :)

Comment: @Sk8erPeter - Yeah, I read through it. It was a good example, but I already do something like that on my own was my point. I kind of prefer to write it myself. Thanks for the link! :)

Answer (score 2):

The major CPU work done in both methods is parsing HTML, generating DOM and painting it on the screen. Preparing the response on the server doesn't escape this. You cannot create DOM on the server or do this work on the server.

So the question is string concatenation on the client vs string concatenation on the server AND sending it over a network. It's kind of a no-brainer.

Comment: The server is sending the data one way or the other...not going to get around that. Thus, the only comparison left is server string concatenation and string creation with a single client side append versus a **multiplicity** of dom appending on client side along with string concatenation, string creation, and dom element creation.

Comment: @TravisJ Yes the server will have to send data either way and the difference is with or without markup. Your client can then concatenate strings with a client side template, which is the only CPU work it will do different to just sending it all from server. In both cases, you have the client parse html, generate DOM and paint it on the screen.

Comment: In the case of server side, the client will not have to parse any html or generate DOM. All it will have to do is render. Have you ever worked with the MVC framework? I get the sense you are not very familiar with asp.net.

Comment: @TravisJ I get the sense you are not very familiar with HTML, Browsers, Server technologies and languages, and HTTP. Otherwise you wouldn't have made such a foolish and incorrect claim.

Comment: @TravisJ asp.net is infamous for abstracting HTTP away like that. What you say is impossible, the server can only send textual data to the client, not its in-memory representation of objects. Please read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP#Technical_overview

Comment: You could also use a tool like google chrome developer tools, and look at its network tab to see what your server is sending when you visit www.myaspnetpage.com or something. It will be html, that your browser has to parse, convert into in-memory object representation (DOM) and paint on the screen. The browser will not have any knowledge that it was generated with asp.net.

Comment: dude, i'm not the one who said `In the case of server side, the client will not have to parse any html or generate DOM. All it will have to do is render.` So I think you've overshadowed me there.

Comment: @Esailija - Sorry I was not verbose enough in my explanation. When I said the client will not have to generate DOM I was referring to the creation of javascript-memory dom elements before actually appending them to the dom. Doing a lot of `document.createElement("div")` can add up versus having the razor engine return an `MvcHtmlString` which already contains `<div><span><div></div></span></div>` in the response. And will not require any use of javascript memory.

Comment: @TravisJ You can use the browsers html parsing engine just with `.innerHTML` or `.insertAdjacentHTML`, where you can just dump the html at once and the effect will be same as dumping it from server at once.

Comment: @Esailija - True, but then the comparison comes in. Which would be faster, creating the html to dump in an innerHTML in javascript memory or creating the html in c# on the server to append from a ajax response.

Comment: @TravisJ dude read the top comment to your question. I did contribute. I told you client side templating is acceptable, depending on the audience, then I told you this question is not in answerable in it's current form.

Comment: @TravisJ So the difference is string concatenation on the client, vs string concatenation on the server. But on the server case, it also needs to be sent over a network, which generally tends to be much slower than just doing it locally in processor.

Comment: @Esailija - The text is coming from a database though, so it will be sent over the network regardless. The ajax request will be sent from the page and a partial view will be populated either with javascript manipulation of a returned JSON array or with just a single html string insertion from the response.

Comment: @TravisJ I am comparing the overhead of sending additional markup with the data that wouldn't have to be sent otherwise. `<div>hello</div>` takes more time to send than just `hello`. Note that in this simple case the instructions the client needs to wrap `hello` with `<div>`  will take more time to send than just `hello` but this isn't a realistic example. The instructions to wrap 10000 hellos with div would take just as much, where as the server would still have to send 10000x more markup.

Comment: @Esailija - That is a good point. The markup could potentially be an exponential change to the data length.